# Use Httpclient.GetStreamAsync() is too slow when ipv6 is not disable in C#

Tags: c#, httpclient, ipv6

Just like C# code, httpClient.GetAsync() use 10 second or more when ipv6 is not disable. But when I disable ipv6 in win10 System, httpClient.GetAsync() just use 200ms.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1Gdq.png)

```
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(handler);
var response = await httpClient.GetAsync("https://ssl.ptlogin2.qq.com");
Console.WriteLine(response.StatusCode);
```

I want to know what causes this difference?

Comment: Sounds like an IPv6 DNS timeout, or something similar.

Comment: If you're using .Net 5 there are some things you can do to help mitigate this: [forcing-httpclient-to-use-ipv4-or-ipv6-addresses](https://www.meziantou.net/forcing-httpclient-to-use-ipv4-or-ipv6-addresses.htm)